# word or phrase for an inconsequential object or activity

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

**TLDR**
Looking for a word or phrase for something that causes no change or has no impact (be it positive or negative) on a situation.

**I NEED MORE**
I'm using the word "asset" in reference to something advantageous or beneficial for an organization, although not in a financial context. My intent is to shed light on something incorrectly perceived as an asset that is, in actuality, something that is at best inconsequential.

**WOW YOU'RE OVERTHINKING IT**
It's a sensitive matter so I don't want to go so far as to call the offending element a "liability". Doing so might sour the audience to my adjoining proposal. Plus, their "thing" isn't actively debilitating or disadvantageous - it just isn't beneficial.

Everyone knows what an asset is. How do you say something isn't an asset without calling it a liability? There's gotta be some middle ground in there somewhere, right?

Example sentence:

> "The website, in its current form is _________ (or is a _______).  It should be an an asset that actively grows your business."

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Could you add a sample sentence with a blank for the word you want?

Comment: Sample sentence, please! Also, did you consider the word "inconsequential"? (You actually used it in your question!)

Comment: hi all, thanks for all the help and your patience. I know I'm splitting hairs here so I wanted to give it some thought and be sure I'm not sending people down an unending rabbit hole.

Comment: Here's my example with some additional comments

"The website, in its current form is [ blank] (or is [a blank]. It should be an an asset that actively grows your business."  Ok so not the best example sentence but frankly, I hadn't gotten that far yet.  But it does accurately portray the context.

 @alwayslearning - In this context I feel like "inconsequential" is a bit condescending. 

Part of the challenge for me here is that audience doesn't/didn't know any better and I don't want to belittle their efforts.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the example sentence from your comment/response.

Comment: If the website is a liability. Overhead is not parallel construction, semantically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider calling it an *overhead* to match your finance-derived terms *asset* and *liability*.

> **overhead** *noun*
>   1 (usually overheads) An overhead cost or expense.
>   ‘overheads, such as lighting, equipment, and any little extras, are paid for out of a centralized fund’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/overhead)

That definition references adjective definition 3 on the same page:

> (of a cost or expense) incurred in the upkeep or running of a plant, premises, or business and not attributable to individual products or items.

On a commercial flight, for example, an extra pilot or two is an asset, but five extra pilots is just overhead.

Here are a couple of examples from the internet:

- HR Is Just Overhead?
  [- ere.net](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=is%20just%20an%20overhead&rlz=1CDGOYI_enAU811AU811&hl=en-GB&prmd=visn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiozrbkiKXdAhXBc94KHXm2AMsQ_AUIEigC)
- Myth: IT is an overhead with no competitive advantage
  [- KPMG](https://home.kpmg.com/au/en/home/insights/2017/04/mid-market-it-competitive-advantage-myth.html)

Comment: I think this is an excellent suggestion because in my experience "overhead" illicits an unspoken connotation of being a "necessary evil" or perhaps being of "lower importance" for many people in business.

Given I was slow to provide feedback I want to give others a chance to chime in before marketing this answered. But so far "overhead" perfectly encapsulates the sentiment I'm trying to convey. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Overhead is neither an inconsequential object nor an activity.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be easier to guess what kind of word you wanted with a sample sentence but as it is I'd suggest.

It has a neutral effect. Or perhaps: it is a neutral element.

> [neutral](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/neutral?s=t=)
>
> not causing or reflecting a change in something: It is believed that the new tax law will be revenue neutral.

Comment: I’d go with *neutral* as well, except it seems the term needs to match *asset* and *liability*, so the OP is probably looking for a noun.

Comment: I see what you mean. Not sure if it's an improvement, but I've added neutral element.

Comment: That definitely helps. Upvoted.

Comment: Thanks, though I have to admit I prefer your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can call it an ***embellishment*** - something *nice to have* but not necessarily serving as an asset.

> The website, in its current form is an ***embellishment***. It should
>   be an an asset that actively grows your business."

ODO:

> **[embellishment](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/embellishment)**
>   *NOUN*
>   **1** A decorative detail or feature added to something to make it more attractive.
>
> ‘While these were practical necessities, in the hands of English
>   craftsmen they were often transformed into decorative embellishments.’

Comment: I quite like that. An adjective along the same lines would be 'cosmetic'. .

Answer (score -1):

- This activity will not bear or yield any fruit.
- This activity will not fructify.
- This activity will not prove productive or fruitful.

  One of these might work.

An asset is expected to provide a return of some kind. If it does not it is not productive or fruitful.

Merriam Webster says this about fructify:

The word also expanded to encompass a figurative sense of "fruit," and it is now more frequently used to refer to the giving forth of something in profit from something else (such as dividends from an investment).

> [fructify](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fructify)